# Gmail search by filetype is failing

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I am trying to filter gmail searches using `filename[filetype]` syntax, specifically for .zip and .jar files.

When I try `filetype:zip`, for example, I am able to see exactly 6 results, which all include .zip attachments.

However, I have been able to manually find many emails with .zip attachments that did not show up in the original filtered search showing exactly 6 results.

This is an issue for me since I am trying to locate several emails with zip files from many years ago. My theory is that the search is looking at the first `N` emails, or the email from `N years ago - NOW`, and ignoring the rest.

Is there a better way to filter searches by filetype or to force gmail to search deeper into my archived emails? Appreciate any useful info.

Answer (score 2):

According to [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), the proper syntax is:

```
filename:zip
```

That worked for me, it returns all results since my Gmail account was created in 2007.

---

From [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en):

[image]

Comment: Good catch Franck.